# Color everything outside a div but within another div in another color

Tags: html, css

I have simulated an A4 page within a div with a white background and if the user writes more than one A4 page, it should expand the page but everything below it should have the background set to red. So instead of jumping to the next page, it should make the user aware that they are over the limit like the picture below:

[image]

```css
.card-a4 {
  min-height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #eee;
}

.card-a4-fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-a4">
  <div class="card-a4-fixed">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with ::after and not a div within a div but not able to solve it either, think it would be a nicer way to solve it though. Also, there can be pages below it so I can't use absolute positioning for just this one page.

I'm thinking it should be doable with just CSS, else I'm using Jquery if it can be solved through javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gradient where you define a size:

```css
.card-a4 {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 
    top
    /100% 100px /* the 100px is the height of coloration, if the div is longer we will see the red */
    no-repeat,
    red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-a4">
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here
</div>

<div class="card-a4">
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here<br>
    Text content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Less HTML code to take care of for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to manage do it with html+css only. I fixed the `card-a4-fixed` height a little so it would be more visual. Also sorry for those 'aaaaa'

```css
.card-a4 {
min-height: 30mm;
    width: 210mm;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #eee;
}
.card-a4-fixed {
  display: inline-block;
    height: 30mm;
    width: 210mm;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #eee;
    max-height: 30mm;
}
body{
background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-a4">
  <div class="card-a4-fixed">

    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
more test more test

  </div>
  <br style="clear: both">
</div>
<div class="card-a4">
  <div class="card-a4-fixed">

    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

  </div>
  <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.innerHeight` and the `top` css value to see if it should be red. Maybe something like this:

```
if(element.style.top >= window.innerHeight) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```